# Chrome extension gives: "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist."

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am developing a chrome extension that will scrape a website and perform click function on it's inner pages.
Here are my files with their respective code:

1. popup.html file:

```
<link href="popup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="module" src="popup.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <button class="btnStart" id="btnStart">Start</button>
</div>
```

2. popup.js file:

```
import { getActiveTabURL } from "./utils.js";

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async () => {
  const activeTab = await getActiveTabURL();

  if (!activeTab.url.includes("example.com")) {
    const container = document.querySelector(".container");
    container.innerHTML = '<div class="title">This is not a example website page.</div>';
    return;
  } else {
      document.getElementById('btnStart').addEventListener('click', function () {
      chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
        const tabId = tabs[0].id;
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, { action: "BEGIN", message: "BEGIN", urlPath: activeTab.url, tabId: tabId }, function (response) {
          // Handle the response here if needed
          console.log("0) outer response in popup.js main script file")
          console.log(response);

          chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ tabId: response.tabId, message: "START", urlPath: response.urlPath }, function (inner) {
            console.log("1) inner response in popup.js main script file")
            console.log(inner);
          });
        });
      });
    });
  }
});
```

3. contentScript.js file:

```
const tryConnect = () => {
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async (msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
        if (msg.action === "scrapeAndClick") {
            console.log("Scraping and Clicking...");

            const messageButtonParent = document.querySelector(".profile-action-compose-option");
            const messageButton = messageButtonParent ? messageButtonParent.querySelector("button") : null;

            if (messageButton) {
                console.log(messageButton.innerText);
            } else {
                console.error("Button not found");
            }

            sendResponse({ complete: true, result: "Scrape and click completed" });
        }

        if (msg.action === "BEGIN") {
            const urlPath = msg.urlPath;
            const tabId = msg.tabId;

            const activeTabPageResultsContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("reusable-search__result-container");
            let individualResultContainer;
            let individualProfileContainer;
            const profileLinks = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < activeTabPageResultsContainer.length; i++) {
                individualResultContainer = activeTabPageResultsContainer[i];
                individualProfileContainer = individualResultContainer.querySelector('.app-aware-link');
                profileLinks.push(individualProfileContainer.getAttribute("href"));
            }

            const item = profileLinks[0];
            console.log("Profile links collected:", { complete: true, result: "Profile links collected", tabId: tabId, message: "START", urlPath: item });
            sendResponse({ complete: true, result: "Profile links collected", tabId: tabId, message: "START", urlPath: item });
        }
    });
};

setTimeout(tryConnect, 1000);
```

4. background.js file:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((obj, sender, sendResponse) => {
    const message = obj.message;
    const urlPath = obj.urlPath;

    if (message === "START") {
        chrome.tabs.create({ url: urlPath, active: false }, function (tab) {
            console.log(`new tab created dynamically with id: ${tab.id}`);
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { action: "scrapeAndClick", message: "scrapeAndClick", urlPath: urlPath, tabId: tab.id }, function (response) {
                    if (response && response.complete) {
                        console.log(response);
                        // sendResponse(response);
                        resolve(response);
                    } else {
                        console.error('Error in scraping and clicking or response is undefined:', response);
                        reject(response);
                    }
                });
            });
        });

        // Return true to indicate that sendResponse will be called asynchronously
        return true;
    }

    // Ensure to resolve the promise even if not using it
    return Promise.resolve();
});
```

5. manifest.json file with following content:

```
{
    "name": "Example page scraping",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "Scraping and submitting forms",
    "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "tabs"
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
        "https://*.example.com/*"
    ],
    "externally_connectable": {
        "matches": [
            "*://*.example.com/*"
        ]
    },
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "*://*.example.com/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "contentScript.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        {
            "resources": [
                "assets/icon-16_x_16.png",
                "assets/icon-24_x_24.png",
                "assets/icon-32_x_32.png"
            ],
            "matches": [
                "https://*.example.com/*"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "action": {
    "default_icon": {
        "16": "assets/icon-16_x_16.png",
        "24": "assets/icon-24_x_24.png",
        "32": "assets/icon-32_x_32.png"
    },
    "default_title": "Example Scaping and Submission",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "manifest_version": 3
}
```

I keep getting following errors:
i) Port disconnected.Content script may not be injected.
ii) "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist."

New tab gets created but after that I get the mentioned errors

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having a misunderstanding here, `chrome.runtime.onMessage` only receives messages send by the `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` method. Therefore, messages send from background using `port.postMessage` won't be received in your content script.

Syncing the communication method between the background and content script will likely solve these problems.

Also, port connections will automatically closed after 5 mins and should be handled.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I tried your suggestion in the following way (inside background.js), but still getting same error:

`return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ tabId: tab.id, message: "scrapeAndClick", action: "scrapeAndClick", urlPath: urlPath }, function (response) {
        sendResponse(response)
    });`

Comment: @GoofyProgrammer could you please provide your updated code mate

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have updated the background.js file code